# Not able to get column datatype

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net, epplus

I am trying to loop through the following code to find DateTime columns. I'm not able to get the code to work. Am I missing something? Thanks.

```
dGrid.DataSource = dSets.Tables(0)
dGrid.DataBind()
ws.Cells(1, 1).LoadFromDataTable(dGrid.DataSource, True)
For i As Byte = 1 To dGrid.Columns.Count
    If dSets.Tables(0).Columns(i).DataType Is GetType(DateTime) Then
        ws.Column(i).Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
    End If
Next

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition"; attachment)
Response.Charset = ""
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Yes you are missing a description of the issue. Does not work is not a proper description.  That said, Office collection indices often start a 1 whereas .Net collection indices start at 0.

Comment: Hello TnTinMn, sorry for not being more descriptive with what I'm trying to get my code to accomplished. Simply I'm trying to get my code to go through each column to find find ones that are DateTime data type. If the type exists, then convert the data values to reflect the mm/dd/yy hh:ss format....I have tried setting the indices with 0 or 1, but the data values remain in the raw state and not changing to the desired format. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there, but need the following changes:

1. Get the column count from `DataSource`.
2. Fix collection indexing.

Tested and working:

```
dataGrid.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)
dataGrid.DataBind()
ws.Cells(1, 1).LoadFromDataTable(dataGrid.DataSource, True)
Dim data = dataGrid.DataSource
' get column count from DataSource: dGrid.Columns.Count is 0
Dim columnCount = data.Columns.Count
For i = 0 To columnCount - 1
    If data.Columns(i).DataType Is GetType(DateTime) Then
        ws.Column(i + 1).Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hello kuujinbo, thanks for the reply. I think your changes would work and deserve the credit. I'm still not able to get mine to work. I narrowed down what the actual problem is. DateTime might not be the right datatype the whole time. I got a chance to look at that data. That specific column is decimal/double variety. I will have to convert this into DateTime. Hopefully this gets back on track. Thanks!

Comment: @ChungLee - You are correct. When you set `Style.Numberformat.Format` it will only work when the data type is `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
For i As Byte = 1 To dGrid.Columns.Count
    If dt.Columns[i].DataType Is GetType(DateTime) Then
        ws.Column(i).Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, TonyW. It's giving me two errors a 'value of type cannot be converted to Boolean' and 'end of statement expected'.

Comment: try this ---   ws.Column(i).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm""

Comment: Hello codeMonger123, I am getting 'DefaultCellStyle is not a member of OfficeOpenXML.ExcelColumn' error.